# Build Dictionary of Arrays Efficiently in julia

Tags: arrays, dictionary, data-structures, julia

I want to save the (x,y) coordinates in a grid network that are visited by different individuals. Let say I have 1000 individuals and the network size is `x = 1:100` and `y=1:100`. I am using `Dict()` and here is a sample code about what I want to do:

```
individuals = 1:1000
x = 1:100
y = 1:100

function Visited_nodes()
   nodes_of_inds =Dict{Int64, Array{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}}()

   for ind in individuals
      dum_array = Array{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}(0)
      for i in x
           for j in y
                if rand()<0.2  # some conditions
                     push!(dum_array, (i,j))
                end
           end
      end
      nodes_of_inds[ind]=unique(dum_array)
   end
   return nodes_of_inds 
end

@time nodes_of_inds = Visited_nodes()

# result:   1.742297 seconds (12.31 M allocations: 607.035 MB, 6.72% gc time)
```

But this is not efficient. I appreciate any advice how to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Please see the [performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/).  Very first piece of advice there: avoid global variables.  `individuals`, `x`, and `y` are all non-constant global variables.  Make them arguments to your function instead.  That change alone speeds up your function by an order of magnitude.

By construction, you're not going to have any duplicate tuples in your `dum_array`, so you don't need to call `unique`.  That shaves off another factor of two.

Finally, `Array{T}` isn't [a concrete type](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/#avoid-containers-with-abstract-type-parameters). Julia's arrays also encode the dimensionality as a type parameter, which must be included for the dictionary of arrays to be efficient. Use `Array{T, 1}` or `Vector{T}` instead.  This isn't a major consideration within the time of this function, though.

The major thing that's left is just the `O(length(individuals)*length(x)*length(y))` computational complexity. Doing *anything* ten million times will add up quickly, no matter how efficient it is.

Answer (score 0):

@Matt B., thanks for your response. About the global variables, I tried a simplified version of my code and it did not help the performance. 
Let say I read my input data from a couple of csv files and I have three functions with different arguments:

```
function Read_input_data()
   # read input data
   individuals = readcsv("file1")
   x = readcsv("file2")
   y = readcsv("file3")
   A = readcsv("file4")
   B = readcsv("file5") # and a few other files

   # call different functions
   result_1 = Function1(individuals , x, y)
   result_2 = Function2(result_1 ,y, A, B)
   result_3 = Function3(result_2 , individuals, A, B)
   return result_1, result_2, result_3 
end

result_1, result_2, result_3 = Read_input_data()
```

I do not know why the performance is not better compared to when I define everything global! I appreciate any if you can comment about this!

Comment: Without more context on what those `FunctionN` calls are doing, it's impossible to say why this is slow.